# Failing to translate the Number of the chapter with Babel

Tags: numbering, chapters, babel, sphinx

I'm using [sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) and `latex` to generate my documentation.

I need to translate the document in another language and I use tha package `babel` (added to the `conf.py` file).

While `babel` translates correctly some parts of the documents (e.x. en Chapter -> it Capitolo) the numbers of the chapter are still in English.

Here a screenshot:

[image]

how can I also translate the number from one to uno?

Another possible solution will be to convert strings to numbers (one to 1).

Anybody has an idea?

**EDIT**

Here the piece of code of the `conf.py` where the custom file sheet is read::

```
# -- Options for LaTeX output ---------------------------------------------
f = open('custom_style.sty', 'r+');
PREAMBLE = f.read();

latex_elements = {
    'babel':'\\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}',
    'maketitle': '',  # No Title Page
    #'papersize':'a4paper'
    #'pointsize':'10pt',
    'preamble' : PREAMBLE
}
```

and I found a way to transform `ONE` into `1`, but it looks like a workaround and I was wondering if the is not a straightforward way to do that.

Here the piece of code of the `custom-style.sty` where I specified the chapter header:

```
% Define new color (same of the default of section)
\definecolor{MSBlue}{RGB}{32, 67, 92}

\usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  % uncomment the following line to have the chapter title of another color
  %{\normalfont\Large \color{MSBlue}}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\filleft\textls{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}} \Large\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft}
```

that brings to the following header:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Most likely, the chapter numbers are somewhat hard-wired into the class or another package, that performs the chapter heading settings. `babel` can replace `macros`, but not explicitly typed text in other commands. Without a working document, this is difficult to tell,however.

Comment: Hi @ChristianHupfer.. The class of the document is `book`.. It would be ok also to change ONE to 1 so there would not be any language issues.. Any idea on how to perform that?

Comment: I have no code to work with -- I can't help you yet

Comment: An answer is impossible without a minimal working example to recreate the problem.

Comment: @clemens.. I've edited the question. Maybe now it is more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally got it.

I change the `language` option in the `conf.py` file and added an option to the `latex_elements` to avoid an annoying error during the compilation:

```
latex_elements = {
    'babel':'\\usepackage[shorthands=off]{babel}'
}

# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
language = 'it'
```

Then I just use `make latexpdf` and the generation of the document is in Italian.

The **ONE** is automatically changed into **1** not only in Italian, but in all the languages I tried.

Anyway, all the *internal variables* like **Note**, **Index**, **Content** are translated too.

Hope this is the right way and that this solution can help also other people.